# uvm set_inst_override for a sequence

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I'm trying to override a sequence by instance.
An example code will describe it best:

```
class my_vir_seq extends base_vir_seq;
    my_seq_c seq1, seq2;

    `uvm_object_utils_begin(my_vir_seq)
      `uvm_field_object(seq1,  UVM_ALL_ON)
      `uvm_field_object(seq2,  UVM_ALL_ON)
    `uvm_object_utils_end

    `uvm_declare_p_sequencer(v_seqr)

    function new(string name = "my_vir_seq");
      super.new(name); 
    endfunction // new 

    virtual task body();
        `uvm_do_on(seq1, p_sequencer.my_seqr)
        `uvm_do_on(seq2, p_sequencer.my_seqr)
    endtask // body
endclass

class my_err_vir_seq extends my_vir_seq;
    my_err_seq_c seq3;

    `uvm_object_utils_begin(my_err_vir_seq)
       `uvm_field_object(seq3,  UVM_ALL_ON)
    `uvm_object_utils_end

    `uvm_declare_p_sequencer(v_seqr)

    function new(string name = "my_err_vir_seq");
      super.new(name); 
      my_seq_c::type_id::set_inst_override(my_err_seq_c::get_type(), "sve.v_seqr.my_err_vir_seq.seq2" );
    endfunction // new 
endclass
```

My aim is to only override `seq2` with `seq3` (its type extends `seq2`'s type). 
I don't get any errors, but the original sequence runs,
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Izhar

Comment: First of all, a small clarification, because you seem to be a bit confused about the overriding mechanism in UVM. When overriding, you're not replacing a specific instance of an object by another instance. You're controlling what type the object is going to have. Thus, a correct way of stating your aim is: "override the type of `seq2` from `my_seq_c` to `my_err_seq_c`". You don't need to define the `seq3` field to benefit from the overriding mechanism (also as you can see from your code, you're not using it at all).

Answer (score 2):

Doing type overrides by instance is (I think) conceptually intended for instances of classes that derive from `uvm_component`, because they have a specific hierarchical path.

There is a trick to do it for sequences as well, using the sequencer's path as an argument to `set_inst_override(...)` (kind of what you tried). You need to do a few changes to your sequence to support this, though. When creating `seq1` and `seq2` you have to give them a context (shown only for `seq2`) so that the factory can find them:

```
// get_full_name() is the third argument
// - the second argument is empty, it's not a typo
seq2 = my_seq_c::type_id::create("seq2", , get_full_name());
```

After you created your sequence, you can start it using `start(...)`:

```
seq2.start(p_sequencer.my_seqr, this);
```

---

The idea is from a DVCon 2013 paper that you can find here: [DVCon 2013 paper](https://s3.amazonaws.com/verificationacademy-news/DVCon2013/Papers/MGC_DVCon_13_Sequence_Sequence_on_the_Wall_Who's_the_Fairest_of_Them_All.pdf)

Comment: Also, as you're doing the override from your `my_err_vir_seq`, make sure that you do a type override by type to replace `my_vir_seq` with it.