# How to use UVM factory's set_inst_override_by_name to override sequence item

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, uvm

I have two sequence item class `a_packet` and its extended class called `bad_packet`.
By default, `a_packet` type is used. 
Trying to override `a_packet` instance with `bad_packet`, I am able to do it successfully by using set_inst_override_by_name in my uvm test,

```
factory.set_inst_override_by_name("a_packet","bad_packet", "*");
```

Now my question is: what if I don't want to use "*", how to know the full hierarchical path of the sequence item instance?

I was trying to utilise get_full_name() from inside the sequence item, right after it is received by the driver, to know the exact hierarchical path. It displayed:

```
uvm_test_top.env.a_agt.a_seqr.a_sequence.a_packet
```

But when I replaced the `*` with above path, the overriding is not happening.

```
factory.set_inst_override_by_name("a_packet","bad_packet","uvm_test_top.env.a_agt.a_seqr.a_sequence.a_packet");
```

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [uvm set\_inst\_override for a sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26100386/uvm-set-inst-override-for-a-sequence)

Comment: The question I linked above deals with sequences, not sequence items, but the process is essentially the same (as sequences are child classes of sequence items).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where you create your packet, you'll need to to specify the full path to the corresponding call to `create(..)`:

```
packet = a_packet::type_id::create("packet", , get_full_name());
```

If you were using the `uvm_do` macro, you'll have to change to using the explicit sequence API:

```
packet = a_packet::type_id::create("packet", , get_full_name());
start_item(packet);
// ... randomize ...
finish_item(packet);
```

Idea is from [this](https://s3.amazonaws.com/verificationacademy-news/DVCon2013/Papers/MGC_DVCon_13_Sequence_Sequence_on_the_Wall_Who's_the_Fairest_of_Them_All.pdf) DVCon Paper, section IV.A.